# How remove note frames of beamer presentation's pages count?

Tags: beamer, notes

I am using the `\note` command to insert note frames in a `Beamer` presentation. I would like to remove these notes frames from pages count even when compiling my presentation with notes enable. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: MWE]

With notes or overlays, the number of pages is not the number of frames, so instead  of `\thepage`  you must use `\insertframenumber`. The number of frames is showed  in the outher theme `infolines` or `Madrid` theme (that load infolines internally) but you can place it anywhere: Example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show  notes}
\newcommand\testpage{
\Huge This is the page \thepage{} and   
the frame \insertframenumber{} of 
a total of \inserttotalframenumber{} frames.
} 
% some themes showing the frame number
% \useoutertheme{infolines}
% \usetheme{Madrid} %use infolines
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{One}
\testpage
\note{\testpage}
\end{frame}
\note{\testpage}
\begin{frame}{Two}
\testpage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Three}
\only<1>{\testpage}
\only<2>{\testpage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```